# How to Pre-select a custom option on a simple product

Tags: custom-options, products

I need to pre-select certain custom options on a Simple product. They will be either drop downs or checkboxes.

Comment: Use javascript on page load complete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [default state of custom option for simple products](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/default-state-of-custom-option-for-simple-products)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for a custom option of type select, so drop down and checkboxes, the html for the values is generated at `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select::getValuesHtml()`.

What I would suggest to display the option defaults on the front end would be to rewrite this block and customize it to set the default options as selected.

For the checkboxes and radio have a look at the section:

```
$htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
if ($arraySign) {
    $checked = (is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue)) ? 'checked' : '';
} else {
    $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
}
```

And for selects and mutli-selects have a look at the section:

```
if ($configValue) {
    $select->setValue($configValue);
}
```