# Set Default Value to custom options for products

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, default-values

I am having custom options created for the products. I need to set some option as default for the custom option so that when user checks on the front end default option will be seen instead of "Please Select".

[image]

I found one Extension [default state of custom option for simple products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/default-state-of-custom-option-for-simple-products)

But I am looking for if I can show at the place where I am creating the options.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php::getValuesHtml()`

Comment (in line no 59) the `addOption` part of

```
$select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().']');
                ->addOption('', $this->__('-- Please Select --'));
```

i.e.

/* -`>addOption('', $this->__('-- Please Select --'));` */

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Great idea.  I just did this and it worked like a charm.  I was looking at an extension that is $699 that does that (plus a little extra).  Then, all you need to do is change the "order" of the values under the custom options.  Thank you!

Comment: I made main product with 0 price, and all the custom product with actual price, Your option is real good to set default option in product details page, how about grid page, i am getting price 0, is there any option to update there?

Comment: not sure why experts like you will post one answer and dont reopen site at all, community need guys like you.....

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the product in that form:

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));//Your website id
    $product->setAttributeSetId(9);//Your attribute code

    $product->setName('A name');
    .
    .
    more attributes you want to set.

After that you need this code:

$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance()->unsetOptions();
$product->setHasOptions(true);

$optionInstance->addOption($this->makeCustomOptions());
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$optionInstance->setProduct($product);

$product->save();


protected function makeCustomOptions(){

        return $option = array(
            'title' => 'Licenses',
            'type' => 'drop_down',//That can be checkbox and more
            'is_require' => 0,//1 if required

            'values'=>array(//These are the options
                array(

                    'title'             => "30 Days",
                    'price'             => -5,
                    'price_type'        => "fixed",
                    'sku'               => "30"
                ),
                array(

                    'title'             => "365 Days",
                    'price'             => -3,
                    'price_type'        => "fixed",
                    'sku'               => "365"
                ),
                array(

                    'title'             => "730 Days",
                    'price'             => -2,
                    'price_type'        => "fixed",
                    'sku'               => "730"
                )
            )

        );
    }
```

And that's it.You can change whatever you want..

Comment: vbak, it doesn't answer a question. Pradeep asked how to choose one custom option as default to avoid having "Please Select" in frontend field.