# Custom option - drop down

Tags: custom-options

I have taken over a webshop and I want to add some new simple products with custom opstions and as a drop down. The previous owner somehow set the default text to something (what is displayed in the drop down before selecting) - Where do I change that default text?

Thanks

See text in drop down - it should say choose size or something
"Ingen gaveindpakning" is not even an option - how do I change that text?

[image]
"Ingen gaveindpakning" is not even an option - how do I change that text?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding , your this custom options will be in product attribute.

1. Simply right click on that select box and click in inspect element.
2. Check the name of that element.
3. go to Catalog-> Attributes-> Manage Attribute
4. Find that element name, then click on that.
5. Then you will see detail page, after that click on last tab in left side-bar
6. You will see list of options for that element now you can change that default text from here.
7. Then save.

Hope i am right, and this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

To add custom option to a simple product, first you select they product you want to add these options to then go to 'Custom Option'. Take a look at [Magento - How to add two colors option for one SKU simple product](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oKowkmCT4s)

Take a look at [default state of custom option for simple products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/default-state-of-custom-option-for-simple-products) or add a screen shot of the admin and frontend of a product with a default option