# How to Set default value for attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I am new to magento. I am trying to show the first weight option of my weight dropdown box selected by default. my product page view is like this[image]

like i want 400gm which is my first option in dropdown seleted while page loads.

can anyone please help me to get this
[image]

Comment: u have add weight in product is custom options or using attribute weight? please define hear

Comment: which magento platform you are using

Comment: check this one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/12902/146

Answer (score -1):

You can get to choose default option in attributes options itself.
goto Catalog->attributes->manage attributes select the appropriate attribute and go to manage label/options and select is default for the required value

[image]

Comment: but i hope this was a custom options using add (weight)

Comment: its not showing dere as i think its not configurable product i set it in costume options

Comment: then please be clear how you need to get the values according to the tags you placed I have answered please let me know what actually you are willing to get

Comment: no need to be configurable products have you created a attribute naming weight??

Comment: i want when some one change weight the price too get updated so i added it in costume options see i added backend pic too

Answer (score -1):

> Select default value for product custom option in Magento using module by **magebuzz**

[image]

> Once you save this option in the backend, the value will be selected
>   by default in product detail page in frontend. Here is how it shows in
>   our site:

[image]

[Moreinfo to go](http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/select-default-value-for-product-custom-option-in-magento)

[download link](https://github.com/magebuzz/Magebuzz_Customoption)

Comment: any thing else can i do other this this tool

Comment: i want make the navigation sticky.. i know the jquery. what is the file name where i add the jquery?