# Magento 1.9 set default for radio button custom option

Tags: custom-options, ce-1.9.1.0

How do i set my radio button custom option to a default value? Now nothing is selected by default.

I suspect I can add or change something in -->

`Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php`?

Comment: Check this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/default-state-of-custom-option-for-simple-products

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are correct, the custom options are rendered from the file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php`

To set a set a radio button custom option to a default value, write this code

```
if($_value->getTitle() == 'Title_of_your_custom_option')
{
    $checked = 'checked';
}
```

before the below code

```
$selectHtml .= '<li>' . '<input type="' . $type . '" class="' . $class . ' ' . $require
                    . ' product-custom-option"'
                    . ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"')
                    . ' name="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']' . $arraySign . '" id="options_' . $_option->getId()
                    . '_' . $count . '" value="' . $htmlValue . '" ' . $checked . ' price="'
                    . $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) . '" />'
                    . '<span class="label"><label for="options_' . $_option->getId() . '_' . $count . '">'
                    . $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '</label></span>';
```

Comment: I got it working, but it seems to add a (new) third option which is then checked by default. So, almost there, but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: post your code here or else try my solution, It works perfectly for me and it wont add a new option

Comment: Not sure how to post that much code, but you can download the file from here (just change .zip to php or txt) [link](http://www.tijdschriftenzo.nl/Select.zip)

Comment: You added the code at the wrong place. look at my answer. i have specified before which `$selectHtml` to add the code

Answer (score 0):

If you have a place to put some JavaScript, you could also check the first radio button in all of these option lists:

```
$('.options-list').find('input[type=radio]').first().prop('checked','checked');
```